# Removing duplicates in a huge .csv file

Tags: python, duplicates

I have a csv file of this format

```
testname unitname time data
test1 1 20131211220159 123123
test1 1 20131211220159 12345
test1 1 20131211230180 1234
```

I am trying to remove all old data from this file and retain only the data with the latest timestamp.(First two of the abovv should be deleted because the last time stamp is greater than the first two timestamps). I want to keep all test data unless the same test and same unit was repeated at a later time. The input file is sorted by time (so older data goes down below).

The file is about 15 Mb.(output_Temp.csv). I copied it as output_temp2.csv

This is what i have.

```
file1=open("output_temp.csv","r")
file2=open("output_temp2.csv","r")
file3=open("output.csv","w")

flag=0
linecounter=0


for line in file1:
    testname=line[0]
    vid=line[1]
    tstamp=line[2]
    file2.seek(0) #reset
    for i in range(linecounter):
        file2.readline() #came down to the line #
    for line2 in file2:
        if testname==line2.split(",")[0] and vid==line2.split(",")[1] and tstamp!=line2.split(",")[2]:
            flag==1
            print line
        if flag==1:
            break

    if flag==0:
        file3.write(line)
    linecounter=linecounter+1 #going down is ok dont go up.
    flag=0
```

This is taking really long to process, I think it might be ok but its literally taking 10 minutes per 100kb and I have a long way to go.

Comment: Your question keeps talking about "the" input file, but your code is clearly processing _two_ input files. What's in each file?

Comment: They are copies. I am picking tokens from the first file, going down the 2nd file.

Comment: You don't need an actual copy of the file for that; you can `open` the same file twice in read mode and get two different file objects.

Comment: The idea is since its sorted and i want the last data, i dont want the condition (of matching testname and unit name and not matching timestamp) to be true for the last entry, which will be the most recent one

Comment: As a side note, you should always `close` files that you `open`—especially files you open in write mode. There's no guarantee that Python will close them automatically, which means there's no guarantee that the last buffer of data will get flushed to disk, so your output file could end up truncated. A `with` statement, as explained in [the tutorial section on files](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), is the best way to do this.

Comment: Also, you might want to consider using the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module instead of parsing these yourself. At some point, you're going to run into CSV files that use quoting or escaping to put commas in the middle of a value, or do something else you didn't expect, and the code to deal with all those edge cases is hard to write and debug; the `csv` module automatically deals with all of it (and has a few other nice things, like the `DictReader` class, to boot).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason this is slow is that you're reading the entire file (or, rather, a duplicate copy of it) for each line in the file. So, if there are 10000 lines, you're reading 10000 lines 10000 times, meaning 10000000 total line reads!

If you have enough memory to save the lines read so far, there's a really easy solution: Store the lines seen so far in a set. (Or, rather, for each line, store the tuple of the three keys that count for being a duplicate.) For each line, if it's already in the set, skip it; otherwise, process it and add it to the set.

For example:

```
seen = set()
for line in infile:
    testname, vid, tstamp = line.split(",", 3)[:3]
    if (testname, vid, tstamp) in seen:
        continue
    seen.add((testname, vid, tstamp))
    outfile.write(line)
```

The [`itertools` recipes](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#recipes) in the docs have a function `unique_everseen` that lets you wrap this up even more nicely:

```
def keyfunc(line):
    return tuple(line.split(",", 3)[:3])
for line in unique_everseen(infile, key=keyfunc):
    outfile.write(line)
```

---

If the set takes too much memory, you can always fake a set on top of a dict, and you can fake a dict on top of a database by using the [`dbm`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/dbm.html) module, which will do a pretty good job of keeping enough in memory to make things fast but not enough to cause a problem. The only problem is that dbm keys have to be strings, not tuples of three strings… but you can always just keep them joined up (or re-`join` them) instead of splitting, and then you've got a string.

---

I'm assuming that when you say the file is "sorted", you mean in terms of the timestamp, not in terms of the key columns. That is, there's no guarantee that two rows that are duplicates will be right next to each other. If there were, this is even easier. It may not *seem* easier if you use the itertools recipes; you're just replacing `everseen` with `justseen`:

```
def keyfunc(line):
    return tuple(line.split(",", 3)[:3])
for line in unique_justseen(infile, key=keyfunc):
    outfile.write(line)
```

But under the covers, this is only keeping track of the last line, rather than a set of all lines. Which is not only faster, it also saves a lot of memory.

---

Now that (I think) I understand your requirements better, what you actually want to get rid of is not all but the first line with the same `testname`, `vid`, and `tstamp`, but rather all lines with the same `testname` and `vid` except the one with the highest `tstamp`. And since the file is sorted in ascending order of `tstamp`, that means you can ignore the `tstamp` entirely; you just want the last match for each.

This means the `everseen` trick won't work—we can't skip the first one, because we don't yet know there's a later one.

If we just iterated the file *backward*, that would solve the problem. It would also double your memory usage (because, in addition to the set, you're also keeping a list so you can stack up all of those lines in reverse order). But if that's acceptable, it's easy:

```
def keyfunc(line):
    return tuple(line.split(",", 2)[:2])
for line in reversed(list(unique_everseen(reversed(list(infile)), key=keyfunc))):
    outfile.write(line)
```

If turning those lazy iterators into lists so we can reverse them takes too much memory, it's probably fastest to do multiple passes: reverse the file on disk, then filter the reversed file, then reverse it again. It does mean two extra file writes, but that can be a lot better than, say, your OS's virtual memory swapping to and from disk hundreds of times (or your program just failing with a `MemoryError`).

If you're willing to do the work, it wouldn't be *that* hard to write a reverse file iterator, which reads buffers from the end and splits on newlines and yields the same way the `file`/`io.Whatever` object does. But I wouldn't bother unless you turn out to need it.

---

If you ever *do* need to repeatedly read particular line numbers out of a file, the [`linecache`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html) module will usually speed things up a lot. Nowhere near as fast as not re-reading at all, of course, but a lot better than reading and parsing thousands of newlines.

You're also wasting time repeating some work in the inner loop. For example, you call `line2.split(",")` three times, instead of just splitting it once and stashing the value in a variable, which would be three times as fast. A 3x constant gain is nowhere near as important as a quadratic to linear gain, but when it comes for free by making your code simpler and more readable, might as well take it.

Comment: Thanks, would you have an example in python?

Comment: This would have worked really well if i did not have duplicates in the test/unit/date that I want to keep. I only want to get rid of old data. Any pointers on how I might do that?

Comment: @Illusionist: I don't understand your requirement. What counts as "old data", and what counts as "duplicate but not old data"?

Comment: @Illusionist: Oh, wait, you want the first two columns to match, and the third to _not_ match? You can do that; let me edit the answer. (This is why code longer than 80 columns is bad; I just assumed that the third condition, which isn't visible on the screen, was the same as the first two…)

Comment: @Illusionist: OK, does my last example (the one that uses `reversed` twice) sound like it does what you want?

Comment: I get an error-  for line in reversed(unique_everseen(reversed(infile), key=keyfunc)):
TypeError: argument to reversed() must be a sequence

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45170/discussion-between-illusionist-and-abarnert)

Answer (score 2):

For this much file size(~15MB) Pandas would be excellent choice.
Like this:

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = pd.read_csv()
clean_data = raw_data.drop_duplicates()
clean_data.to_csv('/path/to/clean_csv.csv')
```

I was able to process a CSV file about 151MB of size containing more than 5.9Million rows in less than a second with the above snippet.
Please note that the duplicate checking can be a conditional operation or a subset of fields to be matched for duplicate checking.
Pandas does provide lot of these features out of the box. Documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/)